# An object as an attribute C++

Tags: c++, object

I have two classes.
As you can see an instance of the first class is an attribute of the second. When I try to create an instance of the second class it's calling the constructor of the first class before the constructor of the second. Is there any way to prevent this?

```
class Date {
    int jour;
    int mois;
    int annee;

public:
    Date();
    Date(int, int, int);
};
class personne {
protected:
    string nom;
    string prenom;
    string CIN;
    Date date_de_naissance;

public:
    personne();
    personne(string, string, string, Date);
    
};
```

Comment: The [initialization order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor#Initialization_order) is fixed in the C++ specification.

Comment: And this is too much of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Why do you think you need to change the initialization order? What problem is that supposed to solve?

Comment: I was about to add an answer but after re-reading it, I am not sure I understand the question any more, but I still put this as a comment: You can call the copy constructor of Date in the constructor of personne:

    personne(string n, string pn, string cin, Date date) 
      : nom(n), prenom(pn), CIN(cin), date_de_naissance(date)
    {}

Comment: No.   Members of a class are initialised (which includes calling their constructor if they have one) before the body of the containing class constructor commences.    You can change how the members are initialised (but not the order of their initialisation) using the constructor initialiser list.

Comment: You can invert things and put `personne` inside of `Date`. More seriously, clarify why on earth you want to construct something before its components?

Answer (score -1):

I found a workaround I can set a default value in the beginning then reset the value of that attribute later in the second class's contructor.

Comment: That's actually not a _"workaround"_, but how it's intended to behave, if you need special default values in `Date`, set them in `Date`'s default constructor.

Comment: this will not "solve" the "problem" described in the question. I suggest you to clarify the question first. Why do you think it is an issue that the constructor of the member is called first? This happens also when you initialize it, hence its not clear what this answer prevents or works around.